# Developing for iPhone 4 and iPhone 5 in one application

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have been away from iOS development for a bit and I am at road block.

One of my apps has a UIImageView graphic and then I have buttons that overlay the visuals. I am able to get everything working except for the autolayout.

If I set my nib to 3.5 and run the simulator in 3.5 mode everything works great. If I run it in 4.0 mode, the buttons all shift. This applies with the reverse of this also.

I'm not sure how to get around the buttons that move. Is there a way or should there be 2 nibs?

Comment: Use autosizing (the ruler icon in the right pane of IB). Also, to see what it looks like on both sizes, click on the button in the bottom right of IB that will expand the views to their sizes on both screen sizes.

Comment: You just need to get your constraints set up properly. I can't say what you need to change without knowing what you're seeing now, and what you want to see. Do you want everything to spread out a little when you go to the larger screen?

Answer (score 2):

If you're not using IB then you would get the size of the view and layout based on that.

I usually use a single value for the verticalOffset (NSInteger) and base Y values on that with different multiples of the value depending on the interface element.

```
CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

if (screenBounds.size.height == 568) { // iPhone 5
    verticalOffset = 20;
} else {
    verticalOffset = 0;
}
```

if in the future Apple releases a iPhone 5.5 with a 768 pixel height (I jest.. ha!)

You would only need to add in a new verticalOffset value and the view would instamagically fill the new size.

```
CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

if (screenBounds.size.height == 768) { // iPhone 5.5
    verticalOffset = 30;
} else if (screenBounds.size.height == 568) { // iPhone 5
    verticalOffset = 20;
} else {
    verticalOffset = 0;
}
```

The **easy way** for IB/iPhone if you want to support older iOS versions turn OFF autolayout

[image: Turn Off AutoLayout]

And turn off auto sizing for the **top value**.

[image]

Layout the view in IB for the iPhone 5 and when you use the iPhone 3.5in all the the interface elements will squeeze into the 3.5in size (make sure you leave enough whitespace when you lay it out in the taller size)

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this good autolayout tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2

Answer (score 0):

Develop in 3.5 inch screen, but enable autoLayout.  Go through each item in your view and adjust the auto sizing.
- Select item
- Go down to where the white arrows are by zoom in/out in interface builder. Click the little button that looks like an H.
- This will allow you to adjust the adjustments for each item

[image]

[image]